# Is it possible to declare a LinkedList field for generic type in a record?

Tags: chapel

Is it possible to declare a LinkedList field for a generic type in a Chapel record?

I think what I'm trying to do is:

```
  record LIST {
    var itm: LinkedList(?t);
  };
```

where the linked list element type `?t` is unknown when the record is declared, but:

```
./Structs.chpl:87: internal error: RES-CAL-NFO-0078 chpl version 1.19.0
Note: This source location is a guess.

Internal errors indicate a bug in the Chapel compiler ("It's us, not you"),
and we're sorry for the hassle.  We would appreciate your reporting this bug --
please see https://chapel-lang.org/bugs.html for instructions.  In the meantime,
the filename + line number above may be useful in working around the issue.
```

Thanks very much!

Comment: Whatever you do, you shouldn't get an internal error, which indicates a bug on our part.  If you'd be willing to file this as a bug on our GitHub issues page (https://github.com/chapel-lang/chapel/issues), that would be awesome.  Otherwise, I'll transcribe it.

Comment: Using the query syntax in the fields of a record/class wasn't something we'd originally planned to support in Chapel, though it's come up from time to time as being attractive.  For example, see this issue and it's follow-on comment(s), and feel free to upvote it or comment on it if you agree:  https://github.com/chapel-lang/chapel/issues/5141

Comment: OK, Brad. It's here: https://github.com/chapel-lang/chapel/issues/13911

Answer (score 6):

In order to do this, you can make the `LIST` type generic.

```
record LIST {
  type T;
  var itm: LinkedList(T);
}

var lst: LIST(int);

writeln(lst.type:string);
writeln(lst.itm.type:string);
```

Produces...

```
LIST(int(64))
LinkedList(int(64))
```

The concrete type of all the fields of `lst` must be known at the point of declaration of `lst`. We make the `LIST` record generic over a type `T`, and then use this type info to instantiate the field `itm`.

See: https://chapel-lang.org/docs/primers/genericClasses.html

Comment: Welcome @londav28 to StackOverflow & enjoy being our active, contributing StackOverflow Community member. You may have already known, that we may document and let and test run the Chapel code live, online, on Try-It-Online **TiO.run** web-based IDE and post also the URL-link to the fully-documented configurable example - as in your case would be: https://tio.run/##S85ILEjN@f@/KDU5vyhFwcczOEShmktBoaSyIFUhxBrIKkssUsgsybVS8MnMy05N8cksLtEI0bTmquXiAknlFJdYgbVpZOaVAIW5yosyS1Jz8jSAEnogU6yKS4oy89KBUsgyQBPRZP//BwA